# Git shows file as modified when I copy paste the exact file from the repo on GitHub

Tags: git

I'm working on a big project, sometimes I add some logging to some files to see how it's functioning, but then I don't want to end up with `git status` that spits out modified for the files that I've played with and with which I don't want to create a new branch.

The problem is that even when I revert to the exact original file `git status` shows the file as modified. Furthermore it has this bizarre modification of `@@ -289,4 +289,4 @@`  which I do not know where it's coming from. I literally just copy and paste the file from GitHub to VSCode.

Any ideas to fix this, I want to play around with loggin and not have them shown in modified.

Comment: Simply use `git restore <file>` to discard changes in the working directory (as `git status` teaches), instead of copy/pasting the file contents from GitHub.

Comment: But why copy-pasting breaks it like this? @mkrieger1

Comment: I don't know maybe the file encoding is different, or the whitespace (tabs vs. spaces, line endings) is different.

Answer (score 0):

The files *are* different, your editor just isn't showing you.

Use `git diff <FILENAME>` to show changes between what's currently checked in vs. what the current file contents are.

Using `git diff -w <FILENAME>` will show you the differences, ignoring whitespace changes.

If you get different output between those two commands, you can be sure you introduced a whitespace change (e.g. tabs turned to spaces, or you're using `CRLF` [Windows] line endings where they were `LF` [Unix] before, etc.).

If you want to simply undo those changes, `git checkout <FILENAME>` or `git restore <FILENAME>` will work.

### Other Things to Check

When I said `git diff <FILENAME>` gives you a diff between what's "currently checked in" that wasn't entirely true. It gives you a diff between (`HEAD` + what's currently *staged* via `git add`) vs. the current contents of the file. To un-stage changes you previously staged, use `git reset <FILENAME>` and re-run your diff.

Git also tracks whether a file's permission bits were changed. Typically it'll show up in the `git diff` output as:

```
diff --git a/some-file b/some-file
old mode 100644
new mode 100755
```

Git only cares about the executable bit. Use a combination of `chmod -x <FILENAME>` or `chmod +x <FILENAME>` to modify permissions. `git checkout <FILENAME>` will also set the permission bits back to what they should be.